# client id not not event exception just after zoho salesiq xhr call

Tags: reactjs, chat, zoho

I have a React Project and encountered this exception:

```
client id not not event
```

Raw:

```
null: client id not not event
  at ? (/teams/5ace3d23fd5dc3053dd04709:0:0)
```

I am using the zoho salesiq (chat widget) and the exception is triggered just after an xhr call to zoho:

```
GET https://salesiq.zoho.com/getembeddetails.ls?widgetcode=...
```

User agent Info:

```
OS:Mac OS X     
Version: 10.13

Browser: Firefox 
Version: 59.0
```

Does someone have any idea of what may be the problem?